# Git head matches SVN head - how to continue committing / tagging to SVN?

Tags: git, git-svn

I was playing around with `git svn set-tree` and managed to set my svn `trunk` match my git repository's trunk. Now that I've managed to `set-tree` I thought I could continue use `git svn` normally, but it didn't work like that.

I want to do a tag to SVN, I do following:

```
git svn -i trunk tag 0.1

Can't call method "full_pushurl" on an undefined value at ...\Git/libexec/git-core\git-svn line 952.
```

I'm running git version 1.7.7.msysgit.1 (under Windows 7 64bit), is this a bug in mysysgit?

I had to use this `-i trunk` thing to get the set-tree working for some reason, I only have one svn remote in `git/config` and am not sure why I have to use the `-i`.

Can I start over, by deleting the git-svn settings and somehow say to my `git svn` that Git head matches SVN head, so that all the commands like `git svn tag` and `git svn dcommit` would work again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use [SmartGit](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/index.html) if I have to use SVN on the server and Git locally. And I create SVN tags by pressing Remote->Push advanced->Push selected tags.

As you use Windows, SmartGit can also be better for you because git-svn is very slow on Windows, but SmartGit doesn't run it but has its own implementation of git-svn written in Java.